# How i can set width in css based on character width?

Tags: css

Rem is font height value. So when we set width in rem for width or media query purpose it depends from character height, not width. I think it's not good for layout.

Comment: unless your font is a monospace one, each character has its own width so technically there is no character width

Answer (score 0):

I find unit for this. It's "ch", but it's not solve problem completely.
[more details about it](https://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2018/06/28/what-is-the-css-ch-unit/)